# How to use second piping with echo and bc commands?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, pipe

I want to use echo|bc commands to calculate big amount of calculation. for example:

```
echo "scale=8; sqrt($NUM)" | bc -l
```

that calculates the square root of NUM to 8 decimal digits accuracy.

now suppose I have a file `numbers.txt` that contain lots of numbers, and I want to calculate the square roots of all of them.

I tried using

```
grep -ow "^[0-9]*$" numbers.txt | xargs -I '{}' echo "scale=8; sqrt({})" | bc -l

grep -ow "^[0-9]*$" numbers.txt | xargs -I '{}' (echo "scale=8; sqrt({})" | bc -l)

grep -ow "^[0-9]*$" numbers.txt | xargs -I '{}' $(echo "scale=8; sqrt({})" | bc -l)

read num numbers.txt | echo "scale=8; sqrt($num)" | bc -l
```

and few more variations of these, but couldn't find a way to make it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! If you are getting some kind of error message when trying those four different variations, could you please update your question with the error output? That would probably be very helpful in trying to find out what problem you are having.

Also, what operating system are you using? That might be important since some command line tools (like `find`, `sed`, and `grep` for instance) don't behave exactly identical on e.g. MacOS compared to most Linux distributions.

Comment: The basic problem is that `xargs` only knows how to execute simple commands -- a command name followed by arguments. Pipes, command substitutions, even "simple" variable substitutions are all beyond what it'll do. Those are all shell features, and you need a shell (not just `xargs`) to do them.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Im using macOS. I found the problem today, it was actually in the grep command. Ill leave the question for future strugglers :)

Comment: If regular floating point precision is sufficient, Awk is probably a better tool for this. `awk '/^[0-9]+$/ { print sqrt($1) }' numbers.txt` and maybe look at the `printf` numeric formats if you need more control over the number of decimals etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line works fine:

```
grep -ow "^[0-9]*$" numbers.txt | xargs -I {} echo "scale=8; sqrt({})" | bc -l
```

Comment: you're right. my problem was actually in the grep command, because my actual file `numbers.txt` has more data in it and not only numbers. the grep pattern should've been `"[0-9]+"` and not `"^[0-9]*$"`

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus before me was right.
my problem was that I have more data in each line, and grep as I used it didn't "greped" it. (`grep "^[0-9]*$"` looked for lines contain only numbers because of th `^` and `$` symbols.

after changing `grep` to `egrep`, the line:

```
egrep -ow "[0-9]+" numbers.txt | xargs -I {} echo "scale=8; sqrt({})" | bc -l
```

solved my problem completely.